# Why I lost my Parameter?

Tags: javascript, json, servlets, query-string

I have a servlet process jsoncallback request.The server uses `getQueryString` got this

```
"jsoncallback=jQuery16208276397785205389_1314579791091&pams={%27title%27:%27%u56DE%u590D%uFF1Afoo%27,%27tag%27:%27%27,%27content%27:%27TEST%27,%27Friedly%27:%27%27,%27IsPrivate%27:%27%27,%27Contact%27:%27%27,%27base%27:5197}&_=1314579902441"
```

But when I use

```
rqs = req.getParameter("pams");
```

the debugger shows rqs is null.
but this works

```
jsoncallback = req.getParameter("jsoncallback");
```

The format seems right.Why I cannot pams get 'pams' parameter?

```
    String rqs = req.getQueryString();
    if (rqs != null) {
        if (req.getParameterMap().containsKey("jsoncallback")) {
            rqs = req.getParameter("pams");
            jsoncallback = req.getParameter("jsoncallback");
        }
        QS = URLDecoder.decode(rqs, "UTF-8");
    }
```

Comment: Where were you when you last saw it? (Sorry, couldn't resist.)

Comment: @Tom Zych you are joking right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because it's not properly [URL-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Those braces, colons and commas are illegal in URLs. I understand that your JSON string originally look like this, right?

```js
var json = {
    'title': '回复：foo',
    'tag': '',
    'content': 'TEST',
    'Friedly': '',
    'IsPrivate': '',
    'Contact': '',
    'base': 5197
};
```

*(which is actually [invalid](http://www.json.org/) JSON, those singlequotes should have been doublequotes)*

You need to serialize the JSON to String first. The JavaScript string representation should look like this:

```
var jsonString = '{"title":"回复：foo","tag":"","content":"TEST","Friedly":"","IsPrivate":"","Contact":"","base":5197}';
```

*(I've for the sake of completeness fixed those invalid singlequotes)*

How to get to that format is left as exercise for you. The [`JSON-js`](http://www.json.org/js.html) is useful in this.

Then, you should have used JavaScript's [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function to URL-encode it into a proper HTTP request parameter value format:

```
var urlEncodedJsonString = encodeURIComponent(jsonString);
```

which should result in this value

```
%7B%22title%22%3A%22%E5%9B%9E%E5%A4%8D%EF%BC%9Afoo%22%2C%22tag%22%3A%22%22%2C%22content%22%3A%22TEST%22%2C%22Friedly%22%3A%22%22%2C%22IsPrivate%22%3A%22%22%2C%22Contact%22%3A%22%22%2C%22base%22%3A5197%7D
```

Finally you can include that value in the query string of your HTTP request and you should be able to use `getParameter()` the usual way (and then feed to some JSON parser like Gson to get a fullworthy Java object out of it). Please note that you don't need to manually URL-decode it. The Servlet API will do it for you when you use `getParameter()` to get the individual parameter instead of manually parsing the query string from `getQueryString()`. That `Map#containsKey()` call is also utterly unnecessary, just get the parameter by `getParameter()`. If it's `null`, then it's simply not been sent, else it is there.